# How to stop ad from my live video streaming?

Tags: html

I am showing live video streaming using simple embeded code:

```
<div class="player_div" align="center">
            <span>
                <script type="text/javascript" src="/resources/scripts/swfobject.js"></script>
                <div id="flashcontent"><embed type="application/x-shockwave-flash" src="/resources/scripts/eplayer.swf" width="772" height="500" style="undefined" id="eplayer" name="eplayer" quality="high" allowfullscreen="true" allowscriptaccess="always" wmode="transparent" flashvars="id=8390&amp;s=star11azza&amp;g=2&amp;a=1&amp;l=&amp;ea=&amp;pk=04aeb981954f677d0740e06bfc7d9d4efd076520b5ee71106e791f45402f0791"></div>
                <script type="text/javascript">
                    var isUpdated = true;

                    function closeUpdateText(test) {
                        isUpdated = true;
                    }

                    var so = new SWFObject("/resources/scripts/eplayer.swf", "eplayer", "772", "500", "9");
                    so.addParam('allowfullscreen','true');
                    so.addParam('allowscriptaccess','always');
                    so.addParam('wmode','transparent');
                    so.addParam('FlashVars', 'id=8390&s=star11azza&g=2&a=1&l=&ea=&pk=04aeb981954f677d0740e06bfc7d9d4efd076520b5ee71106e791f45402f0791');
                    so.write("flashcontent");

                    setTimeout("showUpdateText()", 3000);

                    function showUpdateText() {
                        if (!isUpdated) {
                            document.getElementById("flashcontent").innerHTML="<strong>UPDATE: Please clear your web cache for watching videos!</strong>";
                        }
                    }
                </script>
            </span>
        </div>
```

Some unwanted ad will be shown at the very beginning of play.

[image]
 How can block this Ad programmatically without being installed Ad block in users browser? Any idea?

Comment: From where is the ad coming?

Comment: Use a legit player that doesn't come with ads. E.g. http://www.jwplayer.com/

Comment: I just edited my question to show ad. I am not sure from where the Ad is being come. Actually this is my question. Is this Ad due to any fault in my code?